# a question related to integration inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a integrable function such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt = 1$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty tf(t)\,dt = 0$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2f(t)\,dt = 1$ and $\int_\lambda^\infty f(t)\,dt \leq e^{-a \lambda^2}$ for some constant $a$. Show that $\int_{1/u}^\infty e^{ut}f(t)\,dt \leq e^{O(u^2)} ,\forall u>0$.

Comment: It looks like that your $f(t)$ is a normalized probability density with zero mean and unit variance and is bounded by some Gaussian tail. But if you don't say it's nonnegative, I'm not sure whether the conclusion will hold.

Comment: Yes this question is related to normal distribution. Assuming non negativity how can it be proven, using elementary calculus

Comment: What $O(n^2)$ means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the complementary cumulative distribution function of $f(t)$ be

$$\bar{F}(\lambda)=\int_{\lambda}^\infty f(t)dt\leq e^{-a\lambda^2}.$$

Then we can rewrite the integral

$$\int_{1/u}^\infty e^{ut}f(t)dt=-\int_{1/u}^\infty e^{ut}d\bar{F}(t)=-\left.e^{ut}\bar{F}(t)\right|_{1/u}^\infty+u\int_{1/u}^\infty\bar{F}(t)e^{ut}dt.$$

using integration by parts. The first term becomes $e\bar{F}(1/u)$. The $\infty$ end approaches $0$ because $\bar{F}(\lambda)$ is bounded by the Gaussian tail $e^{-a\lambda^2}$. So we have

$$\int_{1/u}^\infty e^{ut}f(t)dt\leq e^{1-a/u^2}+u\int_{1/u}^\infty e^{-at^2+ut\,}dt.$$

In the $u\rightarrow\infty$ limit, the first integral approaches the constant $e$. The second integral approaches (and is bounded by) the incomplete Gaussian integral

$$u\int_0^\infty e^{-at^2+ut\,}dt=u\int_0^\infty e^{-a(t-\frac{u}{2a})^2+\frac{u^2}{4a}}dt\leq u\,e^{\frac{u^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(t-\frac{u}{2a})^2}dt=u\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{u^2}{4a}},$$

which is then bounded by $e^{Cu^2}$ for any $C>\frac{1}{4a}$ in the $u\rightarrow\infty$ limit.

Comment: $O(u^2)$ means $C.u^2$ for some large constant $C$.

Comment: In the $u\rightarrow 0$ limit or $u\rightarrow\infty$? And is $C>0$ or $C<0$?

Comment: In the limit $u\rightarrow \infty$ and C is positive. Can the second integral be bounded by a sum?

Comment: In the $u\rightarrow\infty$ limit, the first integral approaches a constant. The lower bound of the second integral approaches $0$. Then we basically have a partial Gaussian integral to deal with. We can complete the square and use some asymptotic expansions.